# Spring MVC REST API accepting either JSON or URL parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a current workaround for accepting both JSON and URL parameters in my controller, but it's causing excess duplication in my code. Here's what I've got:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/apicall" method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes"application/json") @ResponseBody
public Object apiCallJSON(ServletWebRequest request, @RequestBody @Valid Object inputs) {
    return apiCall(request, inputs);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/apicall" method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes"!application/json") @ResponseBody
public Object apiCallURLEncoded(ServletWebRequest request, @ModelAttribute @Valid Object inputs) {
    return apiCall(request, inputs);
}

private Object apiCall(ServletWebRequest request, Object inputs) {
    //code to run
}
```

Is there a more natural way to facilitate the option between JSON (by definition in the body of the request, thus using `@RequestBody`) and URL parameters (by definition not in the body, so must use `@ModelAttribute`?

Comment: Have one handler method call the other.  It doesn't stop you from having multiple handler methods, though.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the `@Valid` to be evaluated twice? I guess I could remove it from the first call if that's the case, though. The other annotations (`@ModelAttribute`, `@RequestBody`, and even `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam`) are all specific to `@RequestMapping` and thus ignored if the method is called explicitly, correct?

Comment: I think it's tom-a-toes/tom-ah-toes.  In one hand you have two handlers calling the same service method in a similar way, on the other, you have to jump through some hoops to make one handler call the other.  Which do you prefer?

Comment: @Valid will most probably only be evaluated once as most annotations are only enforced on the Proxies provided by Spring and not when calling directly on this (as you can't really proxy call on this)